# Como cambio la propiedad en find or mongo js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

Quiero cambiar la propiedad a que me busque enteros o valores numericos, igual para acomodar el sort conforme los valores numericos que salgan, pero la verdad no se como, estoy buscando en la propiedad find() de mongoose, pero aun no termino de entender

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo

```
exports.search = (req, res) => {
    //sacar el string a buscar
    var searchString = req.params.search;
    console.log(searchString);
    //find or
    Document.find({ "$or": [
        { "num_folio": { "$regex": searchString, "$options": "i"}},
        { "num_oficio": { "$regex": searchString, "$options": "i"}},
        { "ins_juridico": { "$regex": searchString, "$options": "i"}},
        { "fecha_recepcion": { "$regex": searchString, "$options": "i"}},
        { "remitido": { "$regex": searchString, "$options": "i"}},
        { "origen": { "$regex": searchString, "$options": "i"}},
        { "asignado": { "$regex": searchString, "$options": "i"}},
        { "asunto": { "$regex": searchString, "$options": "i"}},
        { "estatus": { "$regex": searchString, "$options": "i"}},
        { "observacion": { "$regex": searchString, "$options": "i"}}
    ]})
    .sort([['fecha_recepcion', 'ascending']])
    .exec((err, documents) => {
        // console.log(err);
        // console.log(documents);
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send({
                status: 'error',
                message: 'Error en la peticion'
            });
        }
        if (!documents || documents.length <= 0) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                status: 'error',
                message: 'No hay documentos relacionados con tu busqueda!'
            });
        }
        return res.status(200).send({
            status: 'succes',
            documents
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Cuando recibes parámetros desde `body` o `query` recibes un tipo string. Para que express lo compare con otro valor debes hacer el parsing, por ejemplo `body.mi_numero = body.mi_numero * 1`. Hay librerías que te pueden ayudar con esto. Eso es lo que buscas?

Comment: Mi intencion era usar ese dato numerico como referencia principal, tipo ejemplo, si tengo 500 registros, pues ir al 450 sin estar bajando por tanta informacion en la tabla, ya logre hacer el sort sin validar ese campo, pero no se si para la correcta practica sea lo adecuado